How to make a source file read headers from "main.cpp" file?
I would like a source file to have access to included header files from main.cpp source file.
I have 3 files - main.cpp, source.cpp, header.hpp.
header.hpp is included in source.cpp and also in main.cpp.
I would like to make source.cpp source file to read included libraries from main.cpp which are not defined in source.hpp header file and also not in source.cpp source file, for an example to read GLFW/glfw3.h header file.
Example:
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "source.hpp"

...

How can I make source.cpp source file to access included header files from main.cpp file?

Each cpp file AND EACH HPP FILE should #include all of the ddeclarations it needs.  If source.cpp needs something, then it needs to #include it.

This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to do something like that ? If you have common headers you want to include in multiple cpps, you can create a new header which includes those, and then use a single include for the new header in all the cpps. However note it is usually not recommended to have a giant "meta"/"include all" header.

Would be nice to know why you want to this - is it to stop your IDE from flagging everything that has not been #included as an error?   Having a big compilation unit isn't a good idea.  I worked on a project that had big compilation units like yours where all the cpp files were included in the main: took 1.5 days to build.  Split it up and it only took 4 hours.

What you are asking for is not possible in C++.  Every .cpp file is compiled independently, so it must #include everything it needs.  If source.cpp wants access to GLFW/glfw3.h then it needs to #include that header itself, such as in header.hpp, which source.cpp and main.cpp are both using.

In C++, header files included in main.cpp are not automatically accessible in other source files (like source.cpp). Each source file (.cpp) is compiled independently, and they don’t share include files directly.
If you want source.cpp to use the same libraries included in main.cpp (like <GLFW/glfw3.h>), the most straightforward solution is to include the needed headers (e.g., <GLFW/glfw3.h>) directly in source.cpp:
// source.cpp

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "source.hpp"

...

